# Snooze for alarm clock

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, foreach

I have to modify an alarm program for class and I can't see why it's not working. Hoping someone can give me some insight. The way it works right now is that a couple of alarms are loaded when the program starts.

Each alarm is an object of an Alarm class added to an array with the enum AlarmState set to "On". It loops through the array and if one alarm matches the current time and the AlarmState is "On" the alarm goes off, sets a DateTime variable of "snoozeTime" to 5 seconds in the future, and changes the state to "Snooze." However, if it loops through the array and one alarm matches the snoozeTime as well as the state is "Snooze" then it changes the alarm state to "Off."

Right now, the state changes and the snoozeTime variable is set properly. However, the alarm never seems to match the snoozeTime, even though when I print snoozeTime it looks like it matches.
     Also, if you're curious why I'm setting snooze for just 5 seconds in the future, it's because I can't figure out how to use keypresses yet.

This is the relevant part of the main program:

```
// Get current time.
DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime snoozeTime = new DateTime();
// Continually show current time until alarm time reached.
while (alarms.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current time is: {0:HH:mm:ss}", currTime);

    // WRITE LOOP TO CHECK WHETHER ANY ALARMS MATCH.
    foreach (var alarm in alarms)
    {

        if (alarm.Matches(currTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alarm going off at: {0}", alarm.FormattedTime());
            //alarm.Minute += 1;
            snoozeTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5.0);
            alarm.State = AlarmState.Snooze;
            Console.WriteLine("Snooze set for: {0}", snoozeTime);
        }

        if (alarm.Matches(snoozeTime) && alarm.State == AlarmState.Snooze)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting off");
            //set state to off
            alarm.State = AlarmState.Off;
        }
    }  

    Thread.Sleep(1000);  // pause for a second

    currTime = DateTime.Now;  // update current time
}
```

This is the matches method that I'm using:

```
// Returns whether alarm should go off at time "when".
public bool Matches(DateTime when)
{

    return (State != AlarmState.Off && Hour == when.Hour && Minute == when.Minute && Second == when.Second);

    //return (State == AlarmState.On || State == AlarmState.Snooze) &&
        //Hour == when.Hour && Minute == when.Minute && Second == when.Second;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check  `&& alarm.State == AlarmState.On` in your first `if` statement? Else, 5 seconds later it will trigger again your first `if` statement, even if AlarmState is Snooze. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maxime's solution or you could swap your two if-statements - but, a `snooze` doesn't actually work that way - a `snooze` typically triggers the alarm to go off again after a certain time but your `snooze` is killing your alarm

Comment: Thanks Maxine...it was originally in, but I must have lost it while trying to find my problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to me that you are setting a variable to determine when a snoozed alarm should go off, *but then never update the alarm to go off at that time*.

Let's walk through the code with a some sample data:

```
You have 1 alarm set to go off at 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM and current state is on.
The current time is 10/5/2018 12:00:59 PM.
The snooze time is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
```

First time through the loop:
The alarm doesn't match the current time so neither of the if blocks are used.
The program sleeps for 1 second.
Your data looks like this:

```
You have 1 alarm set to go off at 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM and current state is on.
The current time is 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM.
The snooze time is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
```

Now the loop runs again.  The first if block is hit (the alarm time matches the current time (note that the state of the alarm isn't checked here, possibly a bug?). The snooze time is set for 5 seconds into the future and the alarm state is set to snooze.  So after that if block, your data is this:

```
You have 1 alarm set to go off at 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM and current state is snooze.
The current time is 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM.
The snooze time is 10/5/2018 12:01:05 PM.
```

The second if block is now checked.  First, we check to see if the alarm's time (12:01:00 PM) matches the snooze time (12:01:05 PM).  Nope, doesn't match, so we skip the if block.

Let's jump ahead a few iterations of the loop to where the time is 12:01:05 PM (none of the if blocks will have been hit in the mean time).  So your data looks like this:

```
You have 1 alarm set to go off at 10/5/2018 12:01:00 PM and current state is snooze.
The current time is 10/5/2018 12:01:05 PM.
The snooze time is 10/5/2018 12:01:05 PM.
```

The first if block won't get hit (the alarm time of 12:01:00 PM doesn't match the current time 12:01:05 PM).  How about the second if block (the one you are expecting to hit).  First, does the alarm time (12:01:00 PM) match the snooze time (12:01:05 PM)?  Nope, so the alarm never shuts off (your current logic makes it so it will never match).

What I suspect you need to do is something like this (pseudo code so you can figure out the specifics for yourself):

```
//this is within your loop
if alarm matches the current time and the alarm state is on
    calculate the snooze time
    set the alarm's time to go off to the snooze time
    set the alarm's state to snooze

if alarm matches current time and the alarm state is snooze
    shut the alarm off
```

Comment: Yup...I see the problem now. Makes perfect sense once someone else points it out!

Answer (score 2):

As Maxime said as a comment on your question, you should definitely check `alarm.State == AlarmState.On` in your first If statement, otherwise your alarm will match with both if statement consecutively.

What I'm more concerned about is that once `alarm.Matches(currTime)` is met, you set `alarm.State == AlarmState.Snooze` but you seem to never update the time your alarm is set. This meaning `alarm.Matches(snoozeTime) && alarm.State == AlarmState.Snooze` is never true as the time your alarm is set is already past.